# Convert CURL Request to AFNetworking Request

Tags: objective-c, curl, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I would like to use the following curl request in AFNetworking 2.0. Any ideas how I would go about this?

```
curl --request POST -d "login=remitest&password=password&api_version=3" https://8tracks.com/sessions.json
```

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#post-url-form-encoded-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"remitest", @"login",
                        @"password", @"password",
                        @3, @"api_version",
                        nil];
[manager POST:@"https://8tracks.com/sessions.json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // do your stuff
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // fail cases
}];
```

Hope it helps